# react native nesting navigation header bottom style

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

friends. Let me talk about my problem

React navigation v6 version is in use.

My stack is currently nested. The problem is that only the first stack has a lower line of the header and the child stack has no lower line of the header.

And the funny thing is, in the ios simulator, the sub-stack also has a line under the header, but it's not visible on the actual device device.

[image]

This is a picture of a simulator. As you can see, there's a line under the header.

The picture below is a picture of a real device. There is no line under the header.

[image]

Did I write the wrong code overall? If you need my code, please leave a comment. I'll share the code.

Comment: Can you add the code

Comment: Yes, which part should I give you? We can invite you to GitHub if you want!!

Comment: Add navigation code

Comment: There are currently restrictions on this comment to add all the code. If you tell me about GitHub, I'll invite you to GitHub.

Comment: @이승준 add your code on codesandbox and send link here so we can see your code